# Compiling a static version of wxWidgets

Tags: c++, gcc, build, static-libraries, wxwidgets

I tried a lot now but nothing is working.. 
I saw a lot of posts about this and a lot of answeres, but none of it is working for me...
Did anybody successfully build wxWidgets as static and now the right commands?

I downloaded wxWidgets here: http://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/

I tried for example the following commands:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc -j4 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release clean
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc -j4 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release
```

or this:

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc -j4 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release clean
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc -j4 SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release
```

But when the build is finished and I tried to compile a simple programm in Code::Blocks I get a lot of 'undefined reference' errors.

Has anybody experience with it and successfully build a static copie of wxWdigets?
And if so, could you please tell me the commands you used...

I have a dynamic build which I already build and this is working... but I need a static version so I can get a working standalone exe....

Comment: This is a bad question: you ask useless rhetorical questions ("Did anyone successfully build wxWidgets?" -- what do you think the answer is?) and don't give any details about your errors nor show any attempts to actually debug the problem.

Comment: Thats not right... I tried it now for like 20 times without joking...  I mean I can build it but when I want to use it, I get a lot of 'undefined reference' errors, I asked about this error already but nobody could realy give me an answer which worked...

Comment: so i tried to ask if somebody build it by himself so it has to work with his commands.... Because I dont know to do anymore...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how to build wxWidgets, good..but no with mingw, it takes ages...you can try binaries for both compilers, see wx's sourceforge [site](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.2/binaries).